# Unable to get desired results when trying to slice for multiple accounts

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

In my sales report, I have run into a problem where sales for some customers are sold under another customer and I need to attribute sales to both to show truly accurate values.

Pictured below are the tables in question. tblTicketDetails is my facts table with the other two being my dimension tables.
[image]

Here is an example of the accounts in question:

[image]

In the above example, all values in [Account #] belong to customer 1 and values in [LookupAccount] belong to others (lets say customer 2 and 3).
I typically use [Customer Name] as my value in my Slicer as all accounts for a customer are named the same.

The outcome I have been trying to obtain is when I slice by customer 1, I get all values shown in [Account #] that have Customer 1 as the name but if I slice by customer 2 (who lets say has one account and is 5809), I will get all [Account #] that equal 5809 as well as all [Account #] whos [LookupAccount] is also 5809 (so I would also get 23634, 37765, 67804 and 95511).

The same applies to those who have multiple accounts, so if I slice by customer 3 whos accounts are lets say 14650, 89670 and 47900, I would get those results from [Account #] as well as the accounts where {LookupAccount] matches, which in this case would be 19734, 28199 and 64218.

I have tried changing the relationship between tblCustomers and tblTicketDetails, I have also added in the table LookupAccount as an in-between for the many to many relationship but none of those have actually changed the results I get (or they cause the visuals to go blank).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on clarification from the author, here is my updated answer.

There are three objects in this model:

- Sales in `tblTicketDetails`
- Customers in `tblCustomers`
- A matching table between the two, currently `LookupAccount` (the table)

Here is a abstract of the set or rules at stakes :

- A sale has an account number
- A customer is identified by his account number, let's call it *primary account*
- A customer might use *another account number* in some situation. Let's call it *secondary account*

The goal is: **when filtering on a customer, all sales are return whether they are through his primary account or secondary account.**

The maching table `LookupaAccount` needs a rework for the model to function properly. For the stake of clarification, columns are renamed:

- `Account#` → `Primary`
- `LookupAccount` → `Secondary`

Here is an example:

| Primary | Secondary |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

In that example:

- Client account 1 has sales on accounts: 1, or 2, or 3.
- Client account 2 has sales on accounts: 2, or 4.

In PowerQuery, we want to do some transformations:

1. Duplicate `Primary` column and call it `CustomerAccount`. This is the *foreing key* that will links to *tblCustomers*.
2. Unpivot columns `Primary` and `Secondary` with the value column renamed as `ReportingAccount`, which will be the *foreign key* to `tblTicketDetails`

The end result should look like this:

| CustomerAccount | Attribute | ReportingAccount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Primary | 1 |
| 1 | Secondary | 2 |
| 1 | Primary | 1 |
| 1 | Secondary | 3 |
| 2 | Primary | 2 |
| 2 | Secondary | 4 |

Then, you modify the relationships in your model:

- `tblTicketDetails` is connected to `LookupAccount` (table) from field `Account#` to `ReportingAccount`
- `LookupAccount` (table) is connected to `tblCustomers` from field `CustomerAccount` to `Account#`

Normaly this model should flow better.

Now, you can create measure to calculate de amount of sales per customer :

```
SalesperCustomer =
CALCULATE(
    SUM(tblTicketDetails[Total])
)
```

Or, for example just the sales through primary account

```
SalesperCustomer_primary =
CALCULATE(
    SUM(tblTicketDetails[Total])
    LookupAccount[Attribute] = 'Primary'
)
```

Comment: Yes and no. A sale belongs to an account, but sometimes it technically belongs to two. The reason behind this is due to government programs and such, sometimes a sale must be done through a specific account even though that the sale is technically for a different account. Think of it as a pass through account. I need to show its value for the pass through account but I also need to show the value for the account that it is technically for.

Comment: If we put aside the sales. And if I try to rephrase your comment. 
Each customers has : a *primary account* `Account#` and a *secondary account* `LookupAccount`. The desired output is : If you filter on Customer A, with a account 1, you get all lines in `LookupAccount` table with account 1 in either  *primary account* `Account#` and a *secondary account* `LookupAccount` ?

Comment: That sounds correct yes. Customer A has accounts 1-4, so when I filter by Customer A, I get all lines where [Account #] is 1-4 as well as where all [LookupAccount] is also 1-4.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Basically, the `LookupAccount` table needs a little rework in PowerQuery. A basic unpivot columns to cut down the number of relationships.

Comment: Your solution appears to have worked. Now I just need to reconfigure my visuals and double check. Thank you for your help!

Edit:
It 100% works and I am seeing the results I am after. Once again thank you so much!